# Translate chat message based on language that user picks from drop down list

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to get messages translated in real-time in the chat portion of my app depending on the language that the user picks in real-time. For example, if the user only speaks Spanish but messages from the user that they are chatting with are in English, then the user can select 'Spanish' from the dropdown list and all messages that have already been received and all future messages that they will receive will be translated into Spanish. I am capturing the sent message and its translation in each language in firebase but not sure how to get the messages to actually translate on the frontend. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**chat.dart**

```
class Chat extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? peerId;
  final String? peerAvatar;
  final String? name;

  Chat({Key? key, this.peerId, this.peerAvatar, this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: SkapeColors.pageBackgroundFifth,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        backgroundColor: SkapeColors.pageBackground,
        title: Text(
          name!,
          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Brand-Bold', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ChatScreen(
        peerId: peerId,
        peerAvatar: peerAvatar,
        name: name,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? peerId;
  final String? peerAvatar;
  final String? name;

  ChatScreen({Key? key, this.peerId, this.peerAvatar, this.name})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() =>
      ChatScreenState(peerId: peerId, peerAvatar: peerAvatar);
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  ChatScreenState({Key? key, this.peerId, this.peerAvatar, this.name});

  String? peerId;
  String? peerAvatar;
  String? name;
  String? id;

  String? language1 = Translations.languages.first;
  String? language2 = Translations.languages.first;

  final translator = GoogleTranslator();

  static final _apiKey = 'hidden';

  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> listMessage = new List.from([]);
  int _limit = 20;
  int _limitIncrement = 20;
  String groupChatId = "";
  SharedPreferences? prefs;

  File? imageFile;
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isShowSticker = false;
  String imageUrl = "";

  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  _scrollListener() {
    if (listScrollController.offset >=
        listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !listScrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        _limit += _limitIncrement;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(onFocusChange);
    listScrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    readLocal();
  }

  readLocal() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    id = await getUserID();
    if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
      groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
    } else {
      groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
    }

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(id)
        .update({'chattingWith': peerId});

    setState(() {});
  }

  static Future<String> translate(String message, String toLanguageCode) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?target=$toLanguageCode&key=$_apiKey&q=$message'),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final body = json.decode(response.body);
      final translations = body['data']['translations'] as List;
      final translation = translations.first;

      return HtmlUnescape().convert(translation['translatedText']);
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  static Future<String> translate2(
      String message, String fromLanguageCode, String toLanguageCode) async {
    final translation = await GoogleTranslator().translate(
      message,
      from: fromLanguageCode,
      to: toLanguageCode,
    );

    return translation.text;
  }

  Future<void> onSendMessage(String content, int type) async {
    // type: 0 = text, 1 = image, 2 = sticker
    if (content.trim() != '') {
      textEditingController.clear();

      var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        transaction.set(
          documentReference,
          {
            'idFrom': id,
            'idTo': peerId,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
            'content': content,
            'translated': {
              'english': await translate(content, 'en'),
              'spanish': await translate(content, 'es'),
              'german': await translate(content, 'de'),
              'french': await translate(content, 'fr'),
              'russian': await translate(content, 'ru'),
              'italian': await translate(content, 'it'),
              'selectedTranslation': language1,
            },
            'type': type
          },
        );
      });
      listScrollController.animateTo(0.0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
      try {
        String body = content;
        if (content.contains("firebasestorage")) {
          body = "Image";
        }
        var tempResp = await getUserInformation();
        await sendNotificationToUser(
            peerId, "New message from " + tempResp["fullName"], body);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Nothing to send. Please insert your message',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
          textColor: SkapeColors.colorPrimary);
    }
  }

  Widget buildItem(int index, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    String language1 = Translations.languages.first;
    String language2 = Translations.languages.first;
    if (document != null) {
      if (document.get('idFrom') == id) {
        // Right (my message)
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            document.get('type') == 0
            // Text
                ? Container(
              child: TranslationWidget(
                message: document.get('content'),
                fromLanguage: language1,
                toLanguage: language1,
                builder: (translatedMessage)=> MessageWidget(message: document.get('content'), translatedMessage: document.get('content'), isMe: true),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
              width: 215.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 20.0 : 10.0,
                  right: 10.0),
            )
                : document.get('type') == 1
            // Image
                ? Container(
              child: OutlinedButton(
                child: Material(
                  child: Image.network(
                    document.get("content"),
                    loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        Widget child,
                        ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                      if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        width: 200.0,
                        height: 200.0,
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: SkapeColors.colorPrimary,
                            value: loadingProgress
                                .expectedTotalBytes !=
                                null &&
                                loadingProgress
                                    .expectedTotalBytes !=
                                    null
                                ? loadingProgress
                                .cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                                : null,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("here");
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => FullPhoto(
                        url: document.get('content'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
            // Sticker
                : Container(
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/${document.get('content')}.gif',
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 20.0 : 10.0,
                  right: 10.0),
            ),
          ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        );
      } else {
        // Left (peer message)
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  isLastMessageLeft(index)
                      ? Material(
                    child: Image.network(
                      peerAvatar!,
                      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                          ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: SkapeColors.colorPrimary,
                            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes !=
                                null &&
                                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes !=
                                    null
                                ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                                : null,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      errorBuilder: (context, object, stackTrace) {
                        return Image.asset(
                          'images/user_icon.png',
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                        );
                      },
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(35.0),
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  )
                      : Container(width: 35.0),
                  document.get('type') == 0
                      ? Container(
                    child:
                    TranslationWidget(
                      message: document.get('content'),
                      fromLanguage: language1,
                      toLanguage: language1,
                      builder: (translatedMessage)=> MessageWidget(message: document.get('content'), translatedMessage: document.get('content'), isMe: false),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                    width: 215.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 20.0 : 10.0,
                        right: 10.0),
                  ).paddingOnly(left: 12)
                      : document.get('type') == 1
                      ? Container(
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: Material(
                        child: Image.network(
                          document.get('content'),
                          loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                              Widget child,
                              ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                            if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                            return Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(8.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              width: 200.0,
                              height: 200.0,
                              child: Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  color: SkapeColors.colorPrimary,
                                  value: loadingProgress
                                      .expectedTotalBytes !=
                                      null &&
                                      loadingProgress
                                          .expectedTotalBytes !=
                                          null
                                      ? loadingProgress
                                      .cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                      loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                                      : null,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          width: 200.0,
                          height: 200.0,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {

                      },
                  )
                      : Container(
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              )
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
        );
      }
    } else {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
  }

  bool isLastMessageLeft(int index) {
    if ((index > 0 && listMessage[index - 1].get('idFrom') == id) ||
        index == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  bool isLastMessageRight(int index) {
    if ((index > 0 && listMessage[index - 1].get('idFrom') != id) ||
        index == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()=> Future.value(true),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // List of messages
              buildListMessage(),

              // Input content
              buildInput(),
            ],
          ),

          // Loading
          buildLoading()
        ],
      ),
      // onWillPop: onBackPress,
    );
  }

  Widget buildLoading() {
    return Positioned(
      child: isLoading ? const Loading() : Container(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildInput() {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            buildTitle().paddingBottom(10),
            Row(
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: SkapeColors.colorPrimary,
                      autocorrect: true,
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        onSendMessage(textEditingController.text, 0);
                      },
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                      controller: textEditingController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: 'Send Message....',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: SkapeColors.colorTextSemiLight),
                      ),
                      focusNode: focusNode,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Button send message
                  color: SkapeColors.pageBackground,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 155.0,
      // height: 100,
    );
  }

  Widget buildListMessage() {
    return Flexible(
      child: groupChatId.isNotEmpty
          ? StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('messages')
            .doc(groupChatId)
            .collection(groupChatId)
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .limit(_limit)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            listMessage.addAll(snapshot.data!.docs);
            return ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(index, snapshot.data!.docs[index]),
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
              reverse: true,
              controller: listScrollController,
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor:
                AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(SkapeColors.colorPrimary),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      )
          : Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor:
          AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(SkapeColors.colorPrimary),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTitle() => TitleWidget(
    language1: language1,
    onChangedLanguage1: (newLanguage) => setState(() {
      language1 = newLanguage;
    }), key: ValueKey(DropDownWidget),
  );
}
```

**TitleWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/messaging/chatWidgets/DropDownWidget.dart';

class TitleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? language1;
  final ValueChanged<String?> onChangedLanguage1;

  const TitleWidget({
    required this.language1,
    required this.onChangedLanguage1,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [

      Icon(Icons.translate, color: Colors.grey, size: 30,),

      SizedBox(width: 12,),

      DropDownWidget(
        value: language1??"",
        onChangedLanguage: onChangedLanguage1, key: key!,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

**translations.dart**

```
class Translations {
  static final languages = <String>[
    'English',
    'Spanish',
    'French',
    'German',
    'Italian',
    'Russian'
  ];

  static String getLanguageCode(String language) {
    switch (language) {
      case 'English':
        return 'en';
      case 'French':
        return 'fr';
      case 'Italian':
        return 'it';
      case 'Russian':
        return 'ru';
      case 'Spanish':
        return 'es';
      case 'German':
        return 'de';
      default:
        return 'en';
    }
  }
}
```

**MessageWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? message;
  final String? translatedMessage;
  final bool isMe;

  const MessageWidget({
    required this.message,
    required this.translatedMessage,
    required this.isMe,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final radius = Radius.circular(4);
    final borderRadius = BorderRadius.all(radius);

    return Row(
      //To align at different positions based on if message is from the user or not
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 190),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isMe ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary : Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? borderRadius.subtract(BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: radius))
                : borderRadius.subtract(BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: radius)),
          ),
          child: buildMessage(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildMessage() => Column(
    crossAxisAlignment:
    isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      // Text(
      //   message,
      //   style: TextStyle(
      //     color: isMe ? Colors.black54 : Colors.white70,
      //     fontSize: 14,
      //   ),
      //   textAlign: isMe ? TextAlign.end : TextAlign.start,
      // ),
      Text(
        translatedMessage!,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

**TranslationWidget.dart**

```
class TranslationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? message;
  final String? fromLanguage;
  final String? toLanguage;
  final Widget Function(String? translation) builder;

  const TranslationWidget({
    required this.message,
    required this.fromLanguage,
    required this.toLanguage,
    required this.builder,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TranslationWidgetState createState() => _TranslationWidgetState();
}

class _TranslationWidgetState extends State<TranslationWidget> {
  String? translation;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final fromLanguageCode = Translations.getLanguageCode(widget.fromLanguage);
    final toLanguageCode = Translations.getLanguageCode(widget.toLanguage!);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: TranslationApi.translate(widget.message!, toLanguageCode),
      //future: TranslationApi.translate2(
      //    widget.message, fromLanguageCode, toLanguageCode),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return buildWaiting();
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              translation = 'Could not translate due to Network problems';
            } else {
              translation = snapshot.data!;
            }
            return widget.builder(translation??"");
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildWaiting() =>
      translation == null ? Container() : widget.builder(translation??"");
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  What's not working the way you expect?  You're going to have to narrow this down to the bit of code that's problematic.

Comment: @DougStevenson Everything is working as expected. I'm translating the sent messages on the backend. How would I get them to update/change on the front-end in real-time depending on the language that the user selects from the dropdown list of languages? (i.e. a user send a message in English to another user that only speaks Spanish. That user can then select 'Spanish' from the dropdown list to then have all received messages show in Spanish). The function 'onSendMessage' in chat.dart is capturing the message in multiple languages. How do I now get those to show on the front-end?